# The constructor TaskLaunchRequest(String, List<String>, null, null) is undefined - Spring Cloud Task

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-task

I am developing a code for the **Spring Cloud with Spring Boot**. In this example, I am working in `Spring Cloud Tasks`. I was using Spring Boot `<version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>` then below code was working fine. When I updated `<version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>` then I am getting below error.

> The constructor TaskLaunchRequest(String, List, null, null) is undefined

**TaskProcessor.java**

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class TaskProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    public void publishRequest(String payload) {

        //maven://[groupid]:[artifactid]:jar:[version]
        //String url = "maven://pluralsight.demo:pluralsight-springcloud-m3-task:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT";
        String url = "maven://pluralsight.demo:springcloud-m3-tasksink:jar:1.0";

        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(payload.split(",")));

        TaskLaunchRequest request = new TaskLaunchRequest(url, input, null, null);

        System.out.println("created task launch request ...");

        GenericMessage<TaskLaunchRequest> message = new GenericMessage<>(request);
        this.source.output().send(message);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-task.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-task.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-task.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**Error Images:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and after the following modifications in the pom file it works.

1. replace your:

   ```
   <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
   ```

   with:

   ```
   <spring-cloud.version>Brixton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
   ```
2. replace your:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

   with:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-starter</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```